# How to restart a Rails server *gracefully*?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, server, restart, actioncable

TL;DR: Rails-server restarts aren't handled gracefully in Action Cable, resulting in corrupted state. How to fix that?

I run a Rails server which uses Action Cable, among other things.

When I change a file, the server restarts as expected. But it doesn't exactly restart *gracefully*.

The Action Cable connection logs `{"type":"disconnect","reason":"server_restart","reconnect":true}` in the established socket. Then the socket appears to be cut and my channel's `unsubscribed` method does not run. Upon reconnect, however, the `subscribed` method *does* run—as it should, but now we have an asymmetry. Something as simple as keeping track of the number of connected clients has become unreliable because upon a server restart that number will now double although the true number remained the same. That's because it gets to increment the count when `subscribed` is called, but decrementing the counter happens in `unsubscribed`, which is not called when the server restarts.

If this only happened in development, it wouldn't be a huge issue, but it happens in production as well during server restarts caused by deployments.

How do I tell Rails to restart the server *gracefully*, by which I mean it should also run the `unsubscribed` method in my channel instead of just cutting the connection?

EDIT: I've also filed an issue with Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41005

Comment: Why not listen for the disconnect callback on the client-side and trigger a reconnection to the server?  Also, you might find help in this Github issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30678

Comment: "Why not listen for the disconnect callback on the client-side and trigger a reconnection to the server?" Because that wouldn't cover the following use case: server restarts and while server is down the client closes the connection. Then, when the server finishes restarting, the cleanup is never done. More generally speaking, I cannot rely on clients to trigger the cleanup for me. Regarding the link, maybe, but it looks like something else. I'll have to try it.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Abhinay I don't recall.